# What is wrong with this solution?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, logarithms, roots

$$ \ln(x) = 1 + \ln(5)$$

$$ x = e^{1+ \ln(5)} = e^{1+5} = e^6$$

What exactly am I doing wrong here?

Comment: it is $e\cdot 5$ not $e^{1+5}$

Comment: Also $5\ne\ln(5)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You change $\ln(5)$ to $5$ in the exponent, when it should be $$e^{1+\ln(5)}=e\cdot e^{\ln(5)}=5e.$$

Comment: Thank you, can't believe I missed that.

Comment: @ZafarS: You're welcome; we all make mistakes at some point.

Answer (score 1):

$$ \ln x = 1 + \ln 5$$
$$ \ln x = \ln e + \ln 5$$
$$\ln x=\ln(5e)$$
$$x=5e$$